# Selecting text in JTextArea does not show any selection color

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, keylistener

I have this piece of code in which a `JTextArea` is added to a `JFrame`.
Whenever the user presses the <kbd>↑</kbd> key the content of the `JTextArea`
should be selected.

Here is the code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;

public class SelectionTest extends KeyAdapter
{
    final JTextArea jTextArea;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new SelectionTest();
    }

    SelectionTest()
    {
        JFrame jFrame=new JFrame();
        jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jTextArea = new JTextArea("Test 1-2-3");
        jTextArea.addKeyListener(this);
        jFrame.add(jTextArea);
        jFrame.pack();
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if( e.getKeyCode() != KeyEvent.VK_UP ) return;
        jTextArea.selectAll();
    }
}
```

However I observe  that nothing is selected on pressing <kbd>↑</kbd> key,
instead if I slightly change the method `keyPressed` to the following, it works.

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
    if( e.getKeyCode() != KeyEvent.VK_UP ) return;
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            jTextArea.selectAll();
        }
    });
}
```

I want to know reason for this behaviour. Is it a threading issue ?

Comment: Use KeyBindings instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JTextArea` uses arrow keys for moving the caret. You're probably interfering with it. That is why `invokeLater()` helps.

Also, you have to make sure the component is focusable and has focus. Key listener is a lower level interface. As already mention above in the comments, it is better to use Key Bindings instead. See How to [Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for details and examples.

Here is an example based on the posted code that uses key bindings :

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;

public class SelectionTest extends KeyAdapter
{
    final JTextArea jTextArea;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new SelectionTest();
    }

    SelectionTest()
    {
        JFrame jFrame=new JFrame();
        jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jTextArea = new JTextArea("Test 1-2-3");

        Action someAction = new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jTextArea.selectAll();
            }
        };
        jTextArea.getInputMap().put(
                KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0), "someAction");
        jTextArea.getActionMap().put("someAction", someAction);
        
        jFrame.add(jTextArea);
        jFrame.pack();
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Also note that if text area looses its focus it may not show the selection. So you may need to add `jTextArea.requestFocusInWindow()` before altering selection. Also there `selectAll()` that you may use to select all the text. See bug [4320295 : select and selectAll don't work on JTextArea](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4320295) for some details.